# Razor Page - Call method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Well, I'm doing a project using RAZOR PAGES and I have a question because I'm new at this.
Whenever I want to call a method has to be within a form? For instance

I have a button out of a form, as I call a method that is

```
<button (herecallmethod) ></button>

public void Test(){

}
```

I need call method out of form

Comment: Try: `<button>@Model.Test()</button>` - that will call the `public` function called `Test` defined in your model (the `.cs` file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want write a method in cshtml.cs and call method in cs.html out of form.

You can try to use `<a></a>`to call handler in cshtml.cs.
Here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<a asp-page-handler="Test">Test</a>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public void OnGetTest()
        {
            
        }
```

Comment: Result! Its a good option!

Answer (score 0):

To use the method inside the html code using the `Razor` engine you create a `static class` without a `namespace`. Then you can use it throughout the project.

> or if it has a namespace, you should introduce its namespace at the
> top of the view.

Comment: I want write a method in cshtml.cs and call method in cs.html out of form.

Comment: If you want to use the method in defining the button, you must use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods available. Either you would do it inside the form tag. You can investigate the use of @Html.BeginForm. Or you need to add 'onclick' property to the button and catch the event.

```
<button onclick='test()'>button text</button>

function test(){
alert('test')
}
```

Using @html.beginform :
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx

Comment: But i dont want write a function is  js i need write  method in file.cshtml.cs in c#

Comment: Then you can use @Html.BeginForm as I said. You can reach the desired result when you specify the function to be posted.